# Change installation path in VS 2008 setup application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I have created setup file for my C# application using VS 2008
The Application installation default path state as

---

**[ProgramFilesFolder][ManufactureName][ProductName]**

---

I need to change that **[ManufactureName]** to a specific text

---

Ex: **[ProgramFilesFolder][My text][ProductName]**

---

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 3):

Find the .vdproj file within the setup projects folder, open it using a simple texteditor like Notepad, search for

```
 "Manufacturer" = ...
```

and change it to

```
 "Manufacturer" = "8:YourTextHere"
```